# General ORM model contradiction on a one to many relation

Tags: oop, orm, mapping

I have got a very big problem with the mapping of an OOM to a ROM.
Please take a look at the following rules:

- we have got two classes/entities: category and item
- an item is associated with only one category; that means an item can not reference by more than one category
- a category can references more items

That is a simple one to many relation.

The *ROM* looks like the following:

```
category (cId, ...)
item     (iId, ..., cId) cId reference cId from category
```

The *OOM* it is the other way around and looks like (Pseudo-Code):

```
class category
    // the category instance holds all items
    Item[] items;
```

(In OOM we can not be sure that an specific item is contained by only one category.)

Now my question: How can I map this contradiction?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask this question a little bit to quick.

The problem I represent here is one of the generals a OR mapper have to solve.
Every OR mapper should handle this problem so the programmer does not worry about.